# How to cancel telethon NewMessage event, if this message - an album?

Tags: python, events, telegram, telethon

I want to listen two events in Telethon: NewMessage and Album. If my bot is getting new message, i want to check what is this message: album or not. From documentation i have read about Album event, it is good for me that there is this event, but when i get album-message, my programm is calling two events: album event and new message event, i dont want to call new message event if this message is an album, how can i make it?

```
@client.on(events.Album)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.messages[0].peer_id.channel_id == 1859055581:
        await event.forward_to(1859055581)
        print("Album function")
        return 1
    else:
        None
```

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler3(event):
    try:
        await my_event_handler(event)
    except:
        None
    if event.message.peer_id.channel_id == 1859055581:
        if event.message.text != '':
            #await client.forward_message(1859055581, event.messages)
            await event.message.forward_to(1859055581)
            print(event.message.photo)
    else:
        print(event.message)
```

Those are my listener functions

I tried to use Album function in NewMessage function, but it is really doesnt work